# Inline styles in Mosaico

Tags: mosaico

Is it possible to use inline css in Mosaico? I tried it, but it was taken out. It works in Civimail. Thanks. I have been trying to get this working for a while.

Answer (score 2):

I can add inline styles by opening the source code of any text in a block and add in HTML tags with style="" and it works. Are you trying something else? or have I misunderstood your question?

Comment: Hi. This works. I am now grappling with the difference between Outlook, Gmail and other clients. I added padding to a paragraph and it does not display in Outlook. Thank you for your help.